# Converting road number and mile post into coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, traffic

I have a bunch of mile post and road number data and would like to turn it into lat/long coordinates very easily.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please **edit** your question to contain a great deal more information, including:  The GIS software in use, the format of the linear data, the projection of the linear data, the format of the milepost data, and what steps you have taken toward solving this on your own.